# Making a Twitter bootstrap active in C# associated with a Twitter account

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I make this "Latest Tweets" content in my website active? It's a part of my website and I'd like to connect it with my twitter account so whenever I tweet something it appears here automatically. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embeddable timelines make it easy to syndicate any public Twitter timeline to your website with one line of code.

Create an embedded timeline from your widgets settings page on twitter.com, or choose

“[Embed this…](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets)” from the options menu on profile, search and collection pages.

Just like timelines on twitter.com, embeddable timelines are interactive and enable your visitors to reply, Retweet, and favorite Tweets directly from your pages. Users can expand Tweets to see Cards inline, as well as Retweet and favorite counts. An integrated Tweet box encourages users to respond or start new conversations, and the option to auto-expand media brings photos front and center.

These new timeline tools are built specifically for the web, mobile web, and touch devices. They load fast, scale with your traffic, and update in real-time.

https://twitter.com/settings/widgets - this link allows you to do this + twitter supplies you with the iframe code which you insert into your website - easy.